# Clear notifications badge without removing notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

In my app, I'm receiving push notifications with badge number set to one. 
When app will start, it should set badges count to 0, so I'm using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

And it works, but also it removes all notifications from notifications center.
Is there a way to clear badges without removing notifications?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this topic:

[How to clear badge number while preserving notification center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534405/how-to-clear-badge-number-while-preserving-notification-center?rq=1)

setting:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

With iOS9 directly setting badge to negative still clears notifications. You must fire empty UILocalNotification with negative badgenumber to achieve this.

```
let ln = UILocalNotification()
ln.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1
UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(ln)
```

Comment: It works but its a hack, Apple may handle this in future iOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

@feb for ios 9+ you need to set 0 not -1 for that you need to add version condition

```
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }else{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1
    }
```

Comment: This worked in ios 9, but no longer in ios 10 and 11

Comment: this is working now on my code, am also looking for this solution. thanks @KiranSarvaiya

Comment: But 0 will delete all notifications which i do not want

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789581/clear-applicationiconbadgenumber-without-removing-notifications-not-working/41758039#41758039