# Clear applicationIconBadgeNumber without removing notifications not working

Tags: ios, swift, badge

I've read in a few posts (like this one https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7598) that setting

```
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1
```

on `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillEnterForeground` would allow me to clear the badge number without removing the notifications from the notification center. When I set `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber` to a negative number (like -1) it clears all my notifications from the `Notification Center`. Is there another way to clear the badge number without removing the `notifications`?

Comment: what happens when you set it to a positive value like 1 and have 5 notif in the notif center.

Comment: That's a very good question. There is actually no control over how many notifications are in the notification center. You can count them manually, but there are situations where you would get that mistake you’ve just described where your icon badge shows number 1, but you actually have 5 in the notification center.

However, it would be useful in my app just to clear the icon badge number and leave the notifications in the notifications center for when the user needs them.

Comment: yes i didn't mean to say that as a solution. Just wanted to know what would happen in that case. Will the notifications be cleared or just left to last 1 ? Also since you are dealing with push notification i believe - can't you just set the badge number to 0 in them ?

Comment: Nice! I set the badge number to 0 in the payload and the notifications still remain in the notification center, but the icon badge never appears. Interesting! But what if I want to show the icon badge and then clear it out when the user opens the app? It is not possible, is it?

Comment: I actually have not worked with push notifications in a while to actually give definite answers here. Just trying you to help debug and think of solutions. I remembered setting badgeNumber had nothing to do with the notifications in the notification center so this is indeed a new case for me

Comment: Thanks @Shubhank! Appreciate it!

Comment: Hey, Any luck yet ?

Comment: Hi @Shubhank! I ended up implementing your suggestion. I couldn't find any way to clear the badge number without removing the notifications from the notification center. But your suggestion works like a charm. I am going to rely on the sound and the banner so the user knows that there is new information in my app. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I guess this has been introduced with iOS 10. setting applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 also does not help

Answer (score 10):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```

I have tested it in iOS 12.2 and it's working fine for me with remote notification.

It is clearing badge count by keeping received remote notification in notification centre.

Code snippet for reference:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting application badge to -1 indirectly with a empty local notification worked for me, but its a hack to persist notifications in tray while clearing application badge count.

```
if(badgeCount == 0) {
   //set application badge indirectly with UILocalNotification
   UILocalNotification *ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   ln.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:ln];
}
else {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeCount];
}
```

Swift Version

```
if badgeCount == 0 {
    //set application badge indirectly with UILocalNotification
    var ln = UILocalNotification()
    ln.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(ln)
}
else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}
```

Approach tested on iOS 9 and 10.

Comment: which function does this need to be added to!?

Comment: As of iOS 11, this approach is no longer working. However, `[UIApplication sharedApplication]. applicationIconBadgeNumber  = -1` becomes effective again. Apple might be promoting the new @available syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Starting iOS 16 there's a new API, which doesn't have this annoying side effect:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0)
```