# Clearing badge Icon without clearing notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, badge

I have to clear application badge icon while opening the application. I do clear by setting **applicationBadgeIcon** to 0.

=> But it clears my all notifications from notification center. I have also tried by setting **applicationBadgeIcon** to -1, But it also did not work for me.

Is ther Any solution?

Comment: can you provide a code snippet of the according class?

Comment: why don't you store the notifications locally in a database and set the applicationBadgeIcon to 0 ??

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41758039/1864667

Comment: @Markk Yes, I tried this

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 // Badge count was removed.
```

Its working fine for me in Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to achieve will not possible if you pass the **badge** in payload of the push notification. If you any how achieve this behaviour then do one thing remove **badge** number from payload then you did not bother about to clear badge count and your push still display in notification

**disadvantage:**

1) user need to remove all notification one by one same like **instagram**

> Otherwise there is no way to achieve this.