# Clear the applicationIconBadgeNumber but not clear the notice in the iOS notice board

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I want to clear the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` and keep the notification in the notification center for iOS 8 ~ 11.
I have tried the code in the `applicationDidBecomeActive`:

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

It works at the beginning but when I try more times, I can receive the UILocalNotification but can`t change the`applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

Are there any other solutions or is my usage is wrong？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear notifications badge without removing notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674916/clear-notifications-badge-without-removing-notifications)

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674916/clear-notifications-badge-without-removing-notifications/47467746#47467746 answers in this question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code, use

```
if (@available(iOS 9, *)) {
    // iOS 9 (or newer) 
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
} else {
    // iOS 8
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

}
```

to clear app icon badge. This will not clear the notification but counter will become zero on app icon.

You can write this code to clear count in

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

or

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```