# How to clear badge number while preserving notification center in iOS8

Tags: ios, notifications

this question is asked in other several links like [How to clear badge number while preserving notification center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534405/how-to-clear-badge-number-while-preserving-notification-center)

My question is a little more specific.

I would like to clear the badge number when opening app but i want the notificaiton in the notification center to not be cleared.

The suggested answer in the link above is to set the badge number to -1:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1]
```

This works with iOS8? I'm trying without any success.

Thank you

Davide

Comment: Make sure you are clearing the icon's badge number when the applicationDidBecomeActive method is called.

Comment: Hi @Sean , thank you for fast answer. I'm clearing the icon badge (setting it to -1) in the applicationDidBecomeActive. Unfortunatly this clears my notification center too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the doc says, the notification will be gone from notification area when you assign your badge count to 0. <0 will also cause to same effect.